# Getting /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq: Argument list too long error in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to execute an sql query using standardsql in Bigquery which is 224116 characters long with the help of "bq query command line tool" and I am getting following error :

**/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq: Argument list too long error in BigQuery**

Is there any workaround to overcome this error?

There is no error in my query as I am able to execute a smaller query with the same command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no error in my query as I am able to execute a smaller query with the same command

I think you are hitting quotas!
Check [Quota Policy for Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries)

```
Maximum query length: 256 KB
```

*Approximate size based on compression ratios*

> Is there any workaround to overcome this error?

- you can try to split your code into few views and than use those views in main query, so your query will get smaller
- in BQ Standard SQL use WITH (named subqueries) to reuse subqueries