# Cannot run the Google Cloud Shell ※it show too long

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-shell

I used to use cloud shell for roop use to make table at Bigquery.
In this case, Usually I put the google data (360) for make DMP.
sql is going too long so they show below,

[image]

if you have some knowledge to solve this problem ,pls teach me.
※ I Don't wannt to cut the query

Comment: It would help if you enter the command you are running - and instead of a screenshot, paste the error you are getting.

Comment: Is there any chance that you may be hitting some [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#queries)? Check [Argument list too long error in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524896/getting-usr-local-google-cloud-sdk-bin-bq-argument-list-too-long-error-in-bigq) for possible workarounds.